# Where are the CSS styles for Dynamic Data web projects?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

In an ASP.NET Dynamic Data web site/project, all the templates have CSS classes like `CssClass="DDFilter"`, but I can't find these styles anywhere.  Are they served dynamically from a handler or something, or do I have to provide them all myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the default under **`Site.css`** which is automatically made when you create a Dynamic Data project. The Site.css file is located under the root (after creation between global.asax and Site.master)

Grz, Kris.

Comment: Site.css contains none of the classes used in the templates.

Comment: @ProfK What gives you that idea? I can clearly see after creating a test site that the site.css file contains the definition for the DDFilter class. It's being used by Boolean.ascx, Enumeration.ascx, Foreignkey.ascx. 

Also when I simply run that test application and use the IE8 built in developer toolbar I can inspect the elements and the loaded Site.css which is the only css file loaded.

Comment: thanks, you made me create a new site, and the new site.css has the required classes.  Somehow my previous one was overwritten by a previous version site.css.